# What are the values in the output raster when using SAGA majority/minority filter in QGIS returns

Tags: raster, qgis-3, saga, filter

I am using the Majority/Minority SAGA tool in QGIS 3.16.10 on a binary 0,1 raster file to try and smooth the classification. When I run this tool it generates a raster with lots of values between 0 and 1. What do they represent?
Image below showing the resulting image where values range between 0 and 1. My understanding was that the output would be an updated binary image where individual cells have been added to clusters of 0 or 1 cells (depending on the threshold setting)

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce this issue at my end. Could you share your data and the tool setup?

Comment: See here about the prinicples how majority filter works - it's about ArcGIS, but the very principle is not software specific: https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/majority-filter.htm

Comment: Thanks. I understand the concept of Majority filter , so was surprised that the output produced values say 0.12 or 0.24 from an input that has only 0 and 1 value cells. Therefore I was expecting changed cells to be 0 or 1. Hope that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

You may need to convert the raster to an SDAT format before running the Majority filter.